# MySQL Strange Sorting Behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql

When doing a query, I got some strange results when sorting the records.
The records have an 'order' column, but currently they are all set to 0.

When I limit my resultset by 15, everything is as expected. Only when I set the limit to 16, the recordorder goes haywire...

**I know I can fix it with an extra order value, but I want to know why this is happening...**

**LIMIT 15**
[image: LIMIT 15]

**LIMIT 16**
[image: LIMIT 16]

Comment: The result is correct ... in both the case you are only ordering by order .. if you need you can add more then a column to your order by  eg: order by order, product_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue.  You are simple learning that `order by` in MySQL (and SQL in general) is not *stable*.  What this means is that keys with a tied value can occur in an arbitrary order.  So, two different runs of the same query can produce different results.

Why are SQL sorts not stable?  The reason is simple:  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no available information to create a stable sort.  It is meaningless on unordered sets.

The fix?  That's easy.  Just add the keys that you want:

```
order by `order`, product_id
```

Comment: And there's a good reason to have unordered sets: having to maintain such order would imply a permanent performance penalty.

Comment: So, from a limit of 16 my processor does some unlogic thinking? ;)

Comment: @Milkmannetje It just fetches the records that match the condition and are faster to get :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález . . . Your statement is more profound than you might think.  Because it deals with *unordered* sets, SQL is much easier to implement on parallel computers than alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your order:

```
ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

... is not deterministic because there are ties. You should add some additional criteria to undo those ties, e.g. some unique key or primary key:

```
ORDER BY `order` ASC, product_id
```